# Converting python script to bash to run on cygwin

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, cygwin

Is there any way to run python script in cygwin as a bash command,

I'm working on windows7 and install cygwin on my machine, what I need is to run python script on the cygwin (without Installing Python inside Cygwin).
Is there any way to edit python script to run on cygwin or I need to rewrite the script by bash command.

Comment: just pass the full cygwin-converted path of your native windows python as a prefix of your command.

Comment: Are you wanting to *convert* the full script to bash? That depends on how complex the script is.

Comment: Thank you  Jean-François Fabre that I want to do, It seems that my question is very easy :).